# How to solve file.write() new line unexpected output in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write some lines in a file.

My problem arises in the output.

The code looks like this:

```
fileInput = open("file.txt","r+")
fileOutput = open("fileOut.txt","w")
for line in fileInput.readlines():
   outputString = functionname+"="+otherfunctionname+str(lineNumber)
   fileOutput.write(outputString)
   fileOutput.write("\n")
```

The expected output:

```
function()=name=123
function1()=name1=1223
```

Instead the output looks like this:

```
function()
=name=123
function1()
=name1=1223
```

I can't figure out what is the problem. Can you give me a hint of what it could be ?

Comment: Where are you creating `otherfunctionname` ? How are you creating it?

Comment: I'm creating it by parsing the line(before creating outputstring), I gave a general case

Comment: probably `functionname` ends with a new line, strip that off.

Comment: "file.txt" which element are stand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `outputString = functionname.rstrip()+"="+otherfunctionname+str(lineNumber)`